# ReloadEvery on Safari

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-addons, safari

On Firefox there is an add-on called [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115/) that lets you refresh a page on a certain interval. Is there anything like that for Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Finally they came up with a Safari 5 extension for it!

You can get it here: [Auto Reload for Safari 5](http://cl.ly/1LJC)

Remember, it will only work with Safari 5.

Answer (score 1):

http://atbash.net/blog/archives/000135.html

```
-- the applescript only calls attention to itself when the idle period is up
on idle

    tell application "Safari"
    --confirms your browser is the front application
        activate
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            keystroke "r" using {command down}
            end tell
        end tell

    --sets the idle period in seconds.
    --i.e. safari will refresh every 10 seconds
    return 10

end idle
```

If scripting is a bit too advanced for you (you did buy a Mac), try [PageReboot](http://pagereboot.com/).

Comment: Ha ha, It's not to advanced at all, I do it all the time :).

Comment: And the key stroke only works for the frontmost tab, right?  I want it to work for one in the background.

Comment: What is wrong with PageReboot?

Comment: PageReboot doesn't work with SO or SU :(

Answer (score 1):

Document selected when the script is started:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set doc to document 1
    repeat while true
        tell doc to set URL to (get URL)
        delay 10
    end repeat
end tell
```

All tabs:

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat while true
        repeat with t in tabs of windows
            tell t to set URL to (get URL)
        end repeat
        delay 10
    end repeat
end tell
```